# Creating a trigger fires with new insert

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a trigger when a new movie is inserted to the FILM table.

- If a film has SPECIAL_FEATURES 'Trailers' I want to increase the RENTAL_RATE 10c,
- If a film has SPECIAL_FEATURES 'Commentaries' I want to increase the RENTAL_RATE 20c,
- If a film has SPECIAL_FEATURES 'Deleted Scenes' I want to increase the RENTAL_RATE 20c,
- If a film has SPECIAL_FEATURES 'Behind the Scenes' I want to decrease the RENTAL_RATE 20c.

What I have done is,

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RENTALRATE_TRIGGER
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON FILM
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Trailers%' THEN
        UPDATE FILM SET RENTAL_RATE = :NEW.RENTAL_RATE + .10;
    IF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Commentaries%' THEN
        UPDATE FILM SET RENTAL_RATE = :NEW.RENTAL_RATE + .50;
    IF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Deleted Scenes%' THEN
        UPDATE FILM SET RENTAL_RATE = :NEW.RENTAL_RATE + .20;
    IF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Behind the Scenes%' THEN
        UPDATE FILM SET RENTAL_RATE = :NEW.RENTAL_RATE - .20;
    END IF;
END RENTALRATE_TRIGGER;
/
```

I am getting this error after trigger is created.

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
11/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RENTALRATE_TRIGGER" when
         expecting one of the following:
         if
```

SPECIAL_FEATURES column can be something like this, 'Trailers,Behind the Scenes'

Thanks.

Comment: First off, if you're storing a comma-separated list of values in a single column, you're violating every rule of normalization there is.  It appears that you're pretty new to PL/SQL so it seems highly unlikely that you would want to start off with a terribly incorrect data model.  Are you certain that you don't want to create a separate table that maps a file to its special features?

Comment: Hi Justin,
I know what you say and I agree with that. It is a uni assignment and it is a big table includes everything I mentioned in my question.

Comment: It is a lamentable feature of university assignments that they seem designed to produce poor programmers by enshrining bad practice.  Although I suppose if university lecturers were any good at programming they probably wouldn't be university lecturers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not update the same table in a trigger:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RENTALRATE_TRIGGER
        BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON FILM
        REFERENCING OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW
        FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Trailers%'
        THEN
            :NEW.RENTAL_RATE := :NEW.RENTAL_RATE + .10;
        ELSIF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Commentaries%'
        THEN
            :NEW.RENTAL_RATE := :NEW.RENTAL_RATE + .50;
        ELSIF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Deleted Scenes%'
        THEN
            :NEW.RENTAL_RATE := :NEW.RENTAL_RATE + .20;
        ELSIF :NEW.SPECIAL_FEATURES LIKE '%Behind the Scenes%'
        THEN
            :NEW.RENTAL_RATE := :NEW.RENTAL_RATE - .20;
        END IF;
    END RENTALRATE_TRIGGER;
```

Comment: Note that this will only apply one special feature rate.  If there are multiple entries in the list, only one rate differential will be applied.